# Azure Logic App deployment via Powershell

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I have developed a powershell script that allows me to download the Logic Apps from the portal in Visual Studio. Along with the JSON template it also downloads the parameters defined in the Logic App (which is how I wanted). We had established connections with Dataverse and Salesforce via Sign in method. But the problem is that when I download the template via Powershell script and update the parameter file to deploy to a different environment it asks for the credentials which are for service principal login. I haven't used service principal login when creating the connection and I don't have those credentials. I tried removing those parameters from both the parameter file and .JSON file but I am getting error as below:

Error: Code=InvalidDeploymentParameterValue; Message=The value of deployment parameter 'commondataservice-5_token:clientSecret' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference.

These parameters were automatically added in my parameter.json file.

```
"commondataservice-5_token:clientId": {
      "value": null
    },
    "commondataservice-5_token:clientSecret": {
      "value": null
    },
    "commondataservice-5_token:resourceUri": {
      "value": null
    },
    "commondataservice-5_token:grantType": {
      "value": "code"
    }
```

This is how the main Logic App template looks like for the dataverse connection

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "name": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_name')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/',parameters('logicAppLocation'),'/managedApis/commondataservice')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_displayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "token:clientId": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_token:clientId')]",
          "token:clientSecret": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_token:clientSecret')]",
          "token:TenantId": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_token:TenantId')]",
          "token:resourceUri": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_token:resourceUri')]",
          "token:grantType": "[parameters('commondataservice-5_token:grantType')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Below is the Powershell command to get the LA template:
Get-LogicAppTemplate -LogicApp fc-cus-dev-int-test-param-dynamicexpression -ResourceGroup FC-CUS-DEV-INT-RG -SubscriptionId xxxxx-xxxxxx -Verbose | Out-File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\DynamicExpression-NA.LogicApp.json"

#Powershell command to get the Parameters:
Get-ParameterTemplate -TemplateFile "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\DynamicExpression-NA.LogicApp.json" | Out-File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\DynamicExpression-NA.LAparameters.json"

I have followed this article to download the Logic App: https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/12/21/logic-apps-moving-from-azure-portal-to-visual-studio/

I am having a hard time trying to remove the connection parameters from the parameter file and deploying the LA. Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated

Comment: please show the complete syntax of your PowerShell commands...

Comment: @SoySolisCarlos I have updated the question with the poweshell script that I used to download the LA. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the parameter file with actual values.  When you extract a template it creates the parameter file but for for security reasons any value that should not be public (i.e. password) it does not retrieve the existing value. Those values all show as null in your parameter file.  You need to get those values and update the parameter file before deploying.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Mildenberger for your reply. I have updated the required parameters with the values, but the one I am getting error on is for Common Data Service connection parameter. While creating the connection in the portal I used sign in method, but when I download the template it is asking credentials that are used to sign in as service principal. We are not using service principal to establish the connection and I don't have those credentials. Is there a way to tell Visual studio to ignore those credentials and use the basic username and password to establish the connection with CDS?

Comment: @MariyaSusnerwala what is complaining about the Service Principal?  I assume it is when you are deploying the template - how are you doing that?  Your connection to Azure you need a Service Principal to do the deployment - that seems like what you are missing.  If your Azure roles don't allow you to create the Service Principal you may need someone to create one for you.

Comment: Thanks @Scott for your prompt response. I figured out the issue, I was deploying using the parameter file in the VS but the issue was the parameter file in the staging folder was not in sync with the parameter file I was updating, hence it was still complaining about the service principal being null. I had to look a bit deeper to figure out the issue. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: @MariyaSusnerwala glad you got it worked out.